# How to fix docker swarm issues on registrator

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

This is for only who watched and tried this below pluralsight course.

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/docker-swarm-native-docker-clustering

If any body gone though this please tell me what I am missing

Setup Consul Cluster On manger
Manger 1

```
docker -H tcp://mgr1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul1 --name consul1 -v /mnt:/data -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 53:53 progrium/consul -server -advertise mgr1-IP -bootstrap-expect 3
```

Manger 2

```
docker -H tcp://mgr2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul2 --name consul2 -v /mnt:/data -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 53:53 progrium/consul -server -advertise mgr2-IP -join mgr1-IP
```

Manger 3

```
docker -H tcp://mgr3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul3 --name consul3 -v /mnt:/data -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 53:53 progrium/consul -server -advertise mgr3-IP -join mgr1-IP
```

Setup Swarm On manger
Manger 1

```
docker -H tcp://mgr1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -h mgr1 --name mgr1 -d -p 3376:2376 -v /home/ubuntu/.docker:/certs:ro swarm manage --tlsverify --tlscacert=/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/certs/cert.pem --tlskey=/certs/key.pem --host=0.0.0.0:2376 --replication --advertise mgr1-IP:2376 consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Manger 2

```
docker -H tcp://mgr2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -h mgr2 --name mgr2 -d -p 3376:2376 -v /home/ubuntu/.docker:/certs:ro swarm manage --tlsverify --tlscacert=/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/certs/cert.pem --tlskey=/certs/key.pem --host=0.0.0.0:2376 --replication --advertise mgr2-IP:2376 consul://mgr2-IP:8500/
```

Manger 3

```
docker -H tcp://mgr3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -h mgr3 --name mgr3 -d -p 3376:2376 -v /home/ubuntu/.docker:/certs:ro swarm manage --tlsverify --tlscacert=/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/certs/cert.pem --tlskey=/certs/key.pem --host=0.0.0.0:2376 --replication --advertise mgr3-IP:2376 consul://mgr3-IP:8500/
```

Setup consul slaves

Node 1

```
docker -H tcp://node1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul-agt1 --name consul-agt1 -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8301:8301/udp -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp progrium/consul -rejoin -advertise node1-IP -join mgr1-IP
```

Node 2

```
docker -H tcp://node2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul-agt2 --name consul-agt2 -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8301:8301/udp -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp progrium/consul -rejoin -advertise node2-IP -join mgr1-IP
```

Node 3

```
docker -H tcp://node3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run --restart=unless-stopped -d -h consul-agt3 --name consul-agt3 -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8301:8301/udp -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp progrium/consul -rejoin -advertise node3-IP -join mgr1-IP
```

Setup swarm slaves

Node 1

```
docker -H tcp://node1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d -h join --name join swarm join --advertise=node1-IP:2376 consul://node1-IP:8500/
```

Node 2

```
docker -H tcp://node2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d -h join --name join swarm join --advertise=node2-IP:2376 consul://node2-IP:8500/
```

Node 3

```
docker -H tcp://node3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d -h join --name join swarm join --advertise=node3-IP:2376 consul://node3-IP:8500/
```

Setup RegistratorIn All Machines

Manger 1

```
docker -H tcp://mgr1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Manger 2

```
docker -H tcp://mgr2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Manger 3

```
docker -H tcp://mgr3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Node 1

```
docker -H tcp://node1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Node 2

```
docker -H tcp://node2-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

Node 3

```
docker -H tcp://node3-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem run -d --name reg -h reg -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://mgr1-IP:8500/
```

I am facing 2 problems ,

1. The registrator container not starting

   docker -H tcp://mgr1-IP:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem logs reg

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 Starting registrator v7 ...

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 Using consul adapter: consul://mgr1-IP:8500/

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 Connecting to backend (0/0)

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 consul: current leader  mgr2-IP:8300

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 Listening for Docker events ...

   2016/05/08 06:14:25 cannot connect to Docker endpoint
2. After connecting to the client If I run some container , It is executing on current leader manger machine it self. not in the nodes.

How to fix this two issues?